# Too many redirects issue [redirect loop] after modifying htaccess to https redirect in SocialEngine 4.2.9

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, socialengine

Recently I have installed the ssl certificate for our domain. And as part of https secure redirection, changed the htaccess to redirect to https. It works fine with the home page. But when I am login as a user or as an admin, the redirection fails and getting a message like too many redirects and page loading is failed due to redirect looping back and forth between https and http. Please help me to solve this issue.

Please find the current htaccess file that I am using

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.flatparty.com/$1 [R,L]

  RewriteRule ^(blog)($|/) - [L]

  # Get rid of index.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index\.php
  RewriteRule (.*) index.php?rewrite=2 [L,QSA]

  # Rewrite all directory-looking urls
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
  RewriteRule (.*) index.php?rewrite=1 [L,QSA]

  # Try to route missing files
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} public\/ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(jpg|gif|png|ico|flv|htm|html|php|css|js)$
  RewriteRule . - [L]

  # If the file doesn't exist, rewrite to index
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rewrite=1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

When I access https://www.flatparty.com it works fine. But once I logged in gets the redirection issue.

Comment: Showing us the .htaccess contents might help.

Comment: Please find the htaccess.

Comment: Is it possible that there's something in this SocialEngine software that it redirecting back to http? Like a "site URL" setting that it's comparing the current URL to and redirecting if it doesn't match?

Comment: If I print the statement ` $this->view->siteUrl() ` it always returns http://flatparty.com even if I changed the htaccess to redirect to https

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the fix for the issue !!. It was not the issue with .htaccess content, it was the issue with the server code. The following code was the reason for the redirect loop issue.

```
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$request_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$good_url = "http://" . $host . $request_uri;

header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: $good_url");
```

The .htaccess code is working fine and whenever htaccess redirects url to https and the above mentioned code gets redirected to http and eventually it leads to an infinite loop and request will never completes.

Thanks for the help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: maybe your rewrite module of apace is disabled?

Comment: The rewrite module is enabled that's why the site is redirecting to https. But I guess internally some redirection is happening may be in code that's why getting ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error.